# Tools/purpose behind a specific CSS formatting

Tags: css, code-formatting

Ever since I started doing Web development, I've come across templates and sites that have their css structured as so:

```
#location .shell .holder{  margin: 0 auto;}
```

instead of the traditional:

```
#location .shell .holder{  
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Is there a editor that people are using that does this?  I've run into this quite frequently and was wondering why it's structured like so?  Any benefits for doing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually save on file size by doing this. I use a SASS compiler so I really quickly ran it though a couple of the options.

A file thats normally 53k when expanded, goes down to 48k when written like your first example. Compacting everything down to one line is 42k. Obviously your millage will vary.

When initially creating your site, its purely about style, but once you're ready to deploy its about file size.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the insight, was almost sad that I wasn't going to get an answer :D